# TCP connection drop/ or unable to recieve data over TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a client PC sending me data over TCP using a TCP_client program that I wrote.  Basically, I am sending a "Hello Message" to the server.

```
class Program
{
    const int ourPort = 9090;
    static IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10"), 3000);
    static ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am using my PC to to receive that data using a TCP_server program that I wrote.

```
class Server
{
    private static TcpListener tcpListener;
    static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    static int count = 0;
    public Server()
    {
        //
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
        tcpListener.Start();

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;


        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread.Sleep(2);
        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
        Thread.Sleep(2);

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("socket error");
            Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            client.Close();
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
        count++;

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Console.WriteLine(count + " " + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
    }
```

All that said, the problem I am seeing is that once in a while I will hit the "Socket Error" in the `Catch()` on my TCP_server program.

Error:

> ```
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An exi
> sting connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets
> .SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
>  SocketFlags socketFlags)
>    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 s
> ize)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 s
> ize)
>    at test_tcp_manager.Server.OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) in
>  c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_tcp_manager\test_tcp_ma
> nager\Program.cs:line 52
> ```

The error happen irregularly for a second or a few seconds.  I would like to know why and I would like to know how to fix that.

U**PDATE FROM USER INPUT FOR FIX**
**First Code Fix from user Usr feed back:**

tcp_client code is now looks like this:

```
 class Program
{
    const int ourPort = 9090;
    static IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.22.1.22"), 3000);
    static ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using( TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
                    NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

                    byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");

                    clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and tcp_server code is now looks like this:

```
class Server
{
    private static TcpListener tcpListener;
    static int count = 0;
    public Server()
    {
        //
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket rror");
                Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            }
            count++;

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            Console.WriteLine(count + " " + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't forget to close the client after having sent your message. The connection will keep lingering until the GC decides to shut it down.
2. Flushing a networkstream does nothing. Don't be superstitious and flush everything because it seems safer.
3. You are accepting in a timer. I have never seen this kind of mistake before. Why are you doing that? You should be accepting in a loop all clients that connect, and serve them independently. Why are you throttling the server to one client per timer tick?
4. Remove the sleeping. Whenever you think you need a sleep - think harder.
5. You assume that you will read a "message" on the first Read. Read returns you at least one byte. It does not guarantee anything else. TCP does not have message. Make sure your code can deal with receiving incoming data byte-wise.
6. Use the using statement for all disposable resource and get rid of all those awkward Close calls.

Many problems. Socket programming is hard. Be very careful.

Comment: @ usr  
I updated the code above, does that match with what you suggested?

Comment: That's good progress! (5) is still unresolved. This is a latent bug that you just don't notice for small message sizes. You also need to close `client` on the server when you are done servicing that client.

Comment: how do i fix 5? i don't understand that part. i would just use a bigger size buffer?

Comment: @user3573417 First, understand why your code has a bug. What would happen if the OS chose to give data to you in single-byte chunks? This is legal behavior and it would lead to your app behaving in a faulty way (do you agree?). Make sure you nail this. If you don't understand this issue socket programming will be your torment.